# dhtmlx chart with stackedbar from a column

Tags: dhtmlx

I try to display a chart with stacked bars. The problem is, that I don't know how to get the stacked bar grouped by a column. My grid gets its data from a xml-file.

I used the following code to init my chart:

```
var chart = layout.cells("c").attachChart({
view:"stackedBar",
value:"#data5#",
color:"#36abee",
padding:{left:75, bottom:50, top:50, right:30},
yAxis:{start:0, title:("value")},
xAxis:{},
preset:"column",
border:0
});
```

The Columnstitles look like that:

Attributes/Title - Sample 1 - Sample 2 - Sample 3 - Constant - Result 1 - Result 2 - Result 3

- Attributes = Description of the value (e.g. CO2, H2O ...)
- Sample 1 - 3 = the values in the sample
- Constant = Constant for Calc
- Result 1 - 3 = Result for each Sample

What I need is a stacked bar for each result column with all the Attribute in it. With my code I get only a stacked bar for each row. Can anybody help me out?

Thanks a lot
Dan

Comment: It seems like you got answer here: http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=49503